# Problem building a commandline in tcsh to be executed (by lsf), problems with vars and quotes

Tags: shell, variables, command-line, csh, tcsh

I am using tcsh (contract required, cannot change to bash etc), but am having a problem building up a command based on various conditions for different pieces.

Some names changed to protect the innocent...

If new or old program name, is really chosen earlier on by a preprocessor, and is hardcoded by the time this shell script gets run:

```
set myCMDline = newProgName
set myCMDlineTmpFile = "/tmp/myCMDlineTmpScriptFile.csh"
set bsubQname = "typical"

set bsubResources = "span[hosts=1]"
set myCMDline  = "bsub -q $bsubQname -n 8 -R \"$bsubResources\" $myCMDline"

($myCMDline)
```

Now, I have tried several variations of the above, all not working for some reason or another. The closest I think I get is a complaint about mismatched double-quotes, even when backspacing them.

When I do an echo of $myCMDline, then that looks OK, but the execution of same must somehow be different...

```
set bsubResources = '"span[hosts=1]"'    #double-quotes inside, single-quotes outside
set myCMDline  = "bsub -q $bsubQname -n 8 -R $bsubResources $myCMDline"
```

.

```
set bsubResources = "span[hosts=1]"    #double-quotes inside, single-quotes outside
set myCMDline  = 'bsub -q $bsubQname -n 8 -R "$bsubResources" $myCMDline'
```

.

```
set bsubResources = "span[hosts=1]"    #double-quotes inside, single-quotes outside
set myCMDline  = "bsub -q $bsubQname -n 8 -R '$bsubResources' $myCMDline"
```

etc.

I have also tried dumping to a separate temp script file to source, but that contains the $variable names, not resolved equivalents as I would prefer, as I am doing set, not setenv, and prefer not to put these into shell vars.

First I could not echo the "#!/bin/csh -f" line, it seems to try and execute that rather than echo redirected into the temp script file, and dies.

```
rm -f $myCMDlineTmpFile
echo "#!/bin/csh -f  > $myCMDlineTmpFile
echo "$myCMDline" >> $myCMDlineTmpFile
($myCMDlineTmpFile)
```

Then I tried multi-line echo, which is where I am seeing the local variable names go into the file rather than their contents:

```
/bin/cat > $myCMDlineTmpFile <<EOF
#!/bin/csh -f
$myCMDline

EOF

source $myCMDlineTmpFile
```

And then I am trying to instead use eval:

```
eval `echo "$myCMDline &" `
```

with and without the backticks etc, but complains about unknown variables for the queue name, resources etc.

Adding this echo always looks like what I want to be the commandline, between the >>> and <<<

```
echo "DEBUG - myCMDline= >>>$myCMDline<<<"
```

Please help me solve this puzzle...

Comment: You might want to set your variables like `var=...` not `var = ...`

Comment: @l'L'l — in a C shell script, you can use `set var = value` in those, and the spaces around the `=` are allowed (in `tcsh` 6.14.00 as found on an antique RHEL 5 Linux).  Coming from a Bourne shell background, that seems unintuitive to me, but it is how it works.

Comment: I don't like having to say it, but maybe you need `eval $myCMDline` where you currently have `($myCMDline)`.  Another possibility is to write the script you want to execute to a (temporary) file and then run the shell to execute that file.  Be cautious about `eval` when the user had any say in the input you evaluate; it is generally a huge security risk.  (Beware: I use `tcsh` or `csh` only when forced to do so; I generally use `setenv SHELL /bin/bash; exec bash -l` as the contents of my `.login` file, for any shell that isn't a C shell.)

Comment: @Jonathan - Ive already tried eval and writing to a separate file to run, but am having problems with those as well. Variables are not resolving, the excution is being done using varables that I had intended to have been resolved, and are not shell env vars to be resolved at execution of the commandline. I tried making them shell env vars as well, but that still suffered from unmatched double quotes or other issues.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you need the whole command in a single string?  Why not simply use `bsub -q "$bsubQname" -n 8 -R "$bsubResources" "$myCMDline"` (omitting the incremental assignment to `myCMDline`)?  You can put that in a sub-shell if you like.  Doing it all in one string complicates life enormously.

Comment: And if you're thinking "he hasn't really ready the question yet", you're probably right.  I'm not clear where `lsf` fits into the equation.

Comment: Jonathan, the bsub stuff is LSF, which is actually most of the commandline being built here. The queue name, the resource string and he quotes around it, the number of cores desired, those cores in a single server... The incremental steps are because different bits happen in different conditionals in the script. The LSF part is indeed assembled together, but that is where the problem comes in as well, particularly the quotes around the resources string.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> set myCMDline  = "bsub -q $bsubQname -n 8 -R \"$bsubResources\" $myCMDline"
>
> ($myCMDline)
> ```

This won't work because csh considers this as a single string, so it treats the whole string as one big program name. You have to define an array instead:

```
set myCMDline  = (bsub -q $bsubQname -n 8 -R "$bsubResources" $myCMDline:gaq)
($myCMDline:gaq)
```

Explanation: The `:gaq` is a substitution quotes all strings in the list and keeps each list element intact. This is quite similar to "$@" in bash.

This is documented in [History Substitution](https://web.pa.msu.edu/reference/tcsh-web/History_substitution.html)

> **`g`** Apply the following modifier once to each word.
>
> **`a`** (+) Apply the following modifier as many times as possible to a single word. `a' and `g' can be used together to apply a modifier globally. In the current implementation, using the `a' and `s' modifiers together can lead to an infinite loop. For example, `:as/f/ff/' will never terminate. This behavior might change in the future.
>
> **`q`** Quote the substituted words, preventing further substitutions.

This is relevant due to the text in [variable substitution](https://web.pa.msu.edu/reference/tcsh-web/Variable_substitution.html):

> The `:' modifiers described under [History substitution](https://web.pa.msu.edu/reference/tcsh-web/History_substitution.html), except for `:p', can be applied to the substitutions above. More than one may be used. (+) Braces may be needed to insulate a variable substitution from a literal colon just as with [History substitution](https://web.pa.msu.edu/reference/tcsh-web/History_substitution.html) (q.v.); any modifiers must appear within the braces.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try.